# Can I temporarily install a package with apt

Tags: installation, package-management, apt

I frequently find myself interested in trying out a few different packages to solve a problem, to find out which one I prefer, and compare their benefits. A trivial example might be comparing `emacs`, `vim`, `atom`, `nano`, `sublime`, etc. Sometimes I also want to download a large package, but only use it for the day, and have it uninstall later.

When doing this, I sometimes lose track of the several packages I installed. This is annoying, as I eventually end up with clutter that I'm not using, and am not sure if I need any more.

Is there any way to use `apt`, or another package manager, which will allow me to mark a package I've installed as temporary so that it will either:

- Be removed when I reboot
- Be removed when I `autoclean`/`autoremove`
- Be removed after a certain duration

I'm aware that packages can be marked as manually or automatically installed with `apt`, and this can sometimes allow them to be autoremoved.

Would this work as I expect it to?
Is this recommended?
Do I have any other options?

Comment: What if you want to keep it?

Comment: @fixer1234 - Then I'll simply undo the steps. Most of the time I don't want to keep new packages - especially on a raspberry pi with very little space left. I often only need a program for a single hour.